# How to add printer ricoh 2018d?

Tags: printing

I'm using Linux Mint 13 and got some troubles with installing Ricoh 2018d.

I also have an another printer, "Hewlett-Packard HP LaserJet Professional P1102w" and this was piece of cake. I've just do this:

Menu > Printer > add > pick HP from network printers branch (ricoh is not shown) > next > .. > finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it works

Steps while adding:

1. uri address:

   ipp://192.168.1.220/printer
2. pick (in any of three ways: ppd, database or find by printer model) this printer

   Ricoh Aficio 2018D – **PXL driver** (for me PS doesn't work)
3. additional hardware:

   output option: not installed

   option tray: not installed
4. printet desc according to You

Ad 1:

Do You have any idea how to check the ipp having only printer?

I found out my case ipp, becuase of these:

- IP got from windows (printer already installed)
- Queue got from here http://acksyn.org/?p=175

**Is there a general solution?**

Answer (score 2):

http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-Aficio_2018D

Just use it as a PostScript driver, as the comment section says. It should be somewhere in generic drivers. At the bottom of the page there is PPD file, if you want to use it, but I think you may even go without.

Comment: Could be be more verbose? I don't understand "Just use it as a PostScript driver", what am i supposed to do? :)

Comment: @xliiv When you pick a driver, you have to go to "Generic" section or something like that (I don't have Mint to test it). There should be a small choice of PostScript (in my case there's Generic PostScript Printer, just like this).

Comment: printer prints garbage in a loop, btw thanks for effort :)

Comment: @xliiv Then your driver selection should provide you possibility to "Use PPD file". You can download [this PPD file](http://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=Postscript-Ricoh&printer=Ricoh-Aficio_2018D&show=0) and try to use it. Don't worry, we'll fix it :)

Comment: Before PPD is passed the address with protocol is needed?
Which one should i pick (AppSocket/HP JetDirect, ipp, https, ipp14, ipps, LPD/LPR, samba)? The printer's ip is 192.168.1.220.. .

Comment: AppSocket should work for you. Port can probably stay default. If you're missing something, you might try to reference to [this pdf](http://ptm2.cc.utu.fi/ftp/printing/Ricoh/Aficio/mp4500/Linux/fattach_get.pdf), even though it's a bit old.